# Remove 'email_addresses' action from 'woocommerce_email_customer_details' hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, there is a public static class `WC_Emails`, defined in `/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-emails.php`.

Within that class, there is a reference to a hook called `woocommerce_email_customer_details`. To that hook, an action called `email_addresses` is assigned, which is simply a PHP file that generates some HTML for billing and shipping addresses to be added to email notifications.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', array( $this, 'email_addresses' ), 20, 3 );
```

I am trying to remove that action and can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Here's an example bit of code in my child theme's `functions.php` that does not work:

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_default_addresses');
    function remove_default_addresses() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 
                   array( 'WC_Emails', 'email_addresses' ), 20);
}
```

Instead of the `init` hook there, I have tried `wp-head`.  Since `WC_Emails` is a static function, the above code is the way the WordPress Codex suggests, as far as using an `array()` above, instead of just the action name. Regardless, this doesn't work, either (with just the action name):

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_default_addresses');
function remove_default_addresses() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'email_addresses', 20);
}
```

`20` is the priority on the `add_action` Woo does, and I also understand that a `remove_action()` must have the same priority as what the original `add_action()` had.

No matter what I try, the billing and shipping addresses still appear on the email notifications.

Once that gets working, it will be great! However, there is an additional requirement:  This needs to happen only inside code I have for the `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification` hook in Woo.

In other words, I have other code that fires and generates an email when an order status changes from Pending to Processing (and I have tried my code above with all its variations within that hook as well).  I need the billing and shipping addresses to NOT show only in the custom email that is generated.

Any ideas?  Thanks so much. :)

Comment: Please, could you begin your question telling what you want first clearly (may be with an explicit screen shot), because I don't really understand what you really want, and what you are trying to do. Sorry … Thanks

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec.  Basically, it's removing the shipping and billing addresses from email notifications.  No need for a screenshot on that, I think. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', function ( $email_class ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', array( $email_class, 'email_addresses' ), 20, 3 );
});
```

[Source](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/unhookremove-woocommerce-emails/)

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue